# $x^2+ax-a=0$ Find the value of parameter $a$, so that one root is $3$ times bigger than the other

Tags: proof-verification, quadratics

My thoughts were:

$$ x^2+ax-a=0
-p=-ax (x1x2= -ax) \ -->\ 3x2^2=-ax
$$ $q=-a (x1+x2= -a) $--> $4x= -a$

$x2= -a/4,
\ 3((-a/4)^2)=-ax
,\ a(3a+16x)=0$

$a=0\ 
a=-16x/3
$

But i dont think this is the answer ..

Sorry for such a confusing describtion, i dont know how to use this system yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x^2 + a x - a = 0
$$

Let $x_{1,2}$ be the solutions

$$
(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = x^2 + (-x_1-x_2) x + (x_1 x_2)
$$

The coefficients must match. This is where you made the mistake it should have been $3x_2^2=-a$ not $-ax$.

$$
-x_1-x_2=a\\
x_1 x_2 = -a\\
$$

Now suppose that one root is 3 times the other. Without loss of generality $x_1=3x_2$ (you can always switch names if it is $x_2=3x_1$)

$$
-4x_2=a\\
3x_2^2=-a\\
$$

Add the two equations and you get

$$
3x_2^2-4x_2=x_2 (3x_2-4)=0
$$

so $x_2=0$ in which case you get $a=0$ or $x_2=\frac{4}{3}$ in which case $a=-\frac{4}{3}-\frac{12}{3}=\frac{-16}{3}$.

You just made that error with the $-ax$ rather than $-a$.